# Directory.GetFiles() not working with a pattern of "."

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I have some weird problem when I'm adding the following line into my WPF App.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    foreach(string files in Directory.GetFiles(path,".",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
      tb_FileBrowse.Text = files;

}
```

The thing is that in **FrameWork 3.5** the above method does nothing, not even an error, but if I change it to **FrameWork 4.5**
it Works!. Also if I'm using **Framework 3.5** and change it into ConsolApp like this

```
foreach (string files in Directory.GetFiles(path, ".", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}",files);
}
```

The code give some results.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I think the correct search pattern should be "\*.\*".  Mayby your code contains "\*.\*" but this site replaced the \* with nothing. (I had this problem when I wrote this comment.)  In that case I don't know what the problem is.  to display a \* you should write \\*

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 11):

I tried this and got the same results.  Drilling into the API source code with Resharper reveals that the .NET 3.5 and 4.5 versions of Directory.GetFiles are totally different.

In particular the .NET 4.5 version contains this function (and .NET 3.5 doesn't):

```
private static string NormalizeSearchPattern(string searchPattern)
{
  string searchPattern1 = searchPattern.TrimEnd(Path.TrimEndChars);
  if (searchPattern1.Equals("."))
    searchPattern1 = "*";
  Path.CheckSearchPattern(searchPattern1);
  return searchPattern1;
}
```

Which explains why a search pattern of '.' works on .NET 4.5 but not on 3.5.

You should use '*' or '*.*' for compatibility.

Comment: Out of curiosity and completeness: What about 4.0?

Comment: +1. I'd avoid using "." In Windows "." usually means "current dierctory" (".." is parent) so I personally see no reason why "just current directory" pattern means "all files in the given folder". I bet most people will be completely puzzled by call `GetFiles` with "." as pattern.