# Directory.GetFiles(...) with pattern *.??? returns funny results

Tags: c#, .net, directory, filenames

I am using following Code:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("path/to/dir");
var matchingFiles = di.GetFiles("*.???);
```

As expected, files like

- file.bat
- test.1.xml
- a.txt.txt

are returned. However, there are some funny results. As [the MS-documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) mentions, the shortname is searched too. I also found [the information about the dot-selector working in .NET 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915473/directory-getfiles-not-working-with-a-pattern-of). Still I cannot see this explains following results:

- file1.xml.2
- afilewithoutextension

**Q1:** How can this results be explained.

**Q2:** How can a match for pattern *.[3 arbitrary chars] be achieved.

Comment: Try adding `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` : `Directory.GetFiles("path/to/dir", "*.???",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can this results be explained.

Short names, as you note, are always searched; and they always have a three character extension (even if those characters are spaces).

> How can a match for pattern *.[3 arbitrary chars] be achieved.

Do the check in your code (eg. use a regex). MS-DOS wildcards are very limited, and backwards compatibility requirements makes them yet weaker; they are really only useful for specific matches and not general filtering.

Comment: Any source for shortnames always having the `.3` part?

Comment: @ChriPf The underlying data structure of FAT directories.

Answer (score 3):

Q2) You could use `LINQ` and the [`Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("path/to/dir", "*.*")
    .Where(file => Path.GetExtension(file).TrimStart('.').Length == 3);
```